# Get Duplicate Records and identify the lowest ID then use the lowest ID to populate Id_to_keep field

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I would like to write a script either in SQL 2008 or in VB Excel that will get all the duplicate records then on each duplicate, it will get the lowest id then use that id to populate ID_TO_KEEP field.

Raw Data:

```
ID      COMPANY_NAME       ADDRESS           ZIP CODE    ID TO KEEP

111     HONDA MOTORS       55 Oklahoma City    4301
143     HONDA LTD.         55 Oklahoma City    4301
1321    HONDA CARS         55 Oklahoma City    4301
231     MITSUBISHI         32 Miami            5532
342     MITSUBASHA         28 Miami            9421
1324    MERCEDES BENZ      21 Toronto          4210
3212    MERCEDES CARS      21 Toronto          4210
432     MERCEDES ELECTRIC  24 Orlando          7732
```

What I want to Happen:

```
    ID      COMPANY_NAME       ADDRESS           ZIP CODE    ID TO KEEP

    111     HONDA MOTORS       55 Oklahoma City    4301         111
    143     HONDA LTD.         55 Oklahoma City    4301         111
    1321    HONDA CARS         55 Oklahoma City    4301         111
    231     MITSUBISHI         32 Miami            5532
    342     MITSUBASHA         28 Miami            9421
    1324    MERCEDES BENZ      21 Toronto          4210         1324
    3212    MERCEDES CARS      21 Toronto          4210         1324
    432     MERCEDES ELECTRIC  24 Orlando          7732
```

ID to keep column was populated since those 3 honda companies were considered as the same because they are on the same address and zip code then among those 3 honda, 111 is the lowest ID so it was the one used to populate the ID TO KEEP column on those 3 companies.

On the mercedez benz scenario, even though mercedes electric has the same 1st name it was still not considered the same on the 2 mercedes company above because it has different address and zip code.

Hope someone can help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL-Server, you can use an updateable Common table expression to do this

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  ID, 
            IDTOKEEP,
            MinID = MIN(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ZIPCODE, ADDRESS),
            [Count] = COUNT(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ZIPCODE, ADDRESS)
    FROM    T
)
UPDATE  CTE
SET     IDTOKEEP = MinID
WHERE   [Count] > 1;
```

The first step is to use analytic functions to determine the minimum ID for each the row using the address/zipcode combination, and also determine if there is more than one row with that combination. Then update those rows that are identified as duplicates:

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8df5/1)**

Comment: Thanks for the Response! I'll try this. What if I want wildcard comparison. Cause some address in the raw data is not that clean. Example: "55 Oklahoma City-USA" it will not be counted since its not exactly the same as the others

Comment: It starts to get messy then... Will ZIPCode on it's own be enough to remove ambiguity as to whether they are the same place or not?

Comment: No because there are different address with the same zip

Comment: CNT = COUNT([BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID]) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY [BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_POSTAL_CODE],[BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_1]

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Got that error. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Without seeing the full query it is hard to say, but I'd guess you are missing a comma after the previous column.

Comment: WITH CTE AS
( SELECT [BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID],
   [ID_TO_KEEP],
   MinID = MIN([BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID])OVER (PARTITION BY [BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_POSTAL_CODE],[BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_1],
   CNT = COUNT([BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID])OVER (PARTITION BY [BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_POSTAL_CODE],[BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_1] 
 FROM Merging_File
)
UPDATE CTE
SET [ID_TO_KEEP] = MinID
WHERE CNT>1

SELECT * FROM Merging_File

Comment: You are missing the closing parentheses after [BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_1] --> `MIN([BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID])OVER (PARTITION BY [BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_POSTAL_CODE],[BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_1]` **)** `, CNT = ..`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in few steps:

```
    --find how many rows do you have for every adress
SELECT adress, COUNT(*)  as cnt
INTO #temp1
FROM table1
GROUP BY adress
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 


SELECT MIN(id) AS minID, t.adress
INTO #temp2
FROM table1 AS t
INNER JOIN #temp1 AS T2 ON t.adress = t2.adress 
Group by t.adress;


update t
set minID = t2.minID
--select *
from table1 as t
inner join #temp2 as t2 on t.adress = t2.adress
```

check it:
http://rextester.com/VKWVI82297

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Window Function to get your result in SQL Server:

`--Generate a Temporary Table an populate it
DECLARE @tmp TABLE ([ID] DECIMAL(28),[COMPANY_NAME] varchar(50),[ADDRESS] VARCHAR(50),[ZIP CODE] VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO @tmp (ID, [COMPANY_NAME],[ADDRESS],[ZIP CODE])
    SELECT 111,     'HONDA MOTORS',                '55 Oklahoma City', '4301'
    UNION ALL SELECT  143,     'HONDA LTD.',       '55 Oklahoma City', '4301'
    UNION ALL SELECT  1321,    'HONDA CARS',       '55 Oklahoma City', '4301'
    UNION ALL SELECT  231,     'MITSUBISHI',       '32 Miami',         '5532'
    UNION ALL SELECT 342,     'MITSUBASHA',        '28 Miami',         '9421'
    UNION ALL SELECT 1324,    'MERCEDES BENZ',     '21 Toronto',       '4210'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3212,    'MERCEDES CARS',     '21 Toronto',       '4210'
    UNION ALL SELECT 432,     'MERCEDES ELECTRIC', '24 Orlando',       '7732'
--now get the first id, partitioned by ZIP Code and Address.
select *, min(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY [ADDRESS], [ZIP CODE]) as IDTOKEEP from @tmp`

If you need to evaluate the company too, and the first space character does the job, you can add 
`CASE sign(charindex(' ', COMPANY_NAME)) WHEN 1 THEN left(COMPANY_NAME, charindex(' ', COMPANY_NAME) - 1) ELSE COMPANY_NAME END` to your `PARTITION BY` clause.